# Pass Data to Elasticsearch from a Remote Server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have two PCs. Assueme that they are Server1 and Server2.
Logstash is installed in Server2 and Elasticsearch is configured in Server1. **I want to send filtered logstash data from Server2 to Server1**.
Which configurations shall I do?
(**please give me some example configuaration file of .conf file, Logstash.yml, Elasticsearch.yml**)

Answer (score 0):

.conf file :-

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
}

filter {
}

output {
        elasticsearch {
            id => "DOC_ID"
            document_type => "_doc"
            hosts => ["ELASTICSEARCH_HOST"]
            index => "INDEX_NAME"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... but i need configuratipn without filebeat... do you have any solution?